# django_bootstrap package: set bootsrap width class to fields in form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the package [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) to render forms/formset with boostrap.

I only want to know if there is a way to set to a `{% bootstrap_form %}` or `{% bootstrap_field %}` a class like `.col-md-4`.

The default operation to create a form field (with both template tags) returns something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="id_Descripcion">Ejemplo</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="id_Descripcion" maxlength="50" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Ejemplo" required="required" title="" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap them in another div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@martincpt is right

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="id_Descripcion">Ejemplo</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="id_Descripcion" maxlength="50" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Ejemplo" required="required" title="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/cahufifavi/2/edit?html,output